# How to multiply input given by user for metric system calculator

Tags: python-3.x, system, physics, cs50, metric

I am working on a metric system converter for class using python3 in cs50 but I am having some troubles. Basically, I want the user to input a number(value) and then he'd choose the prefix of measurement(ex: kilo, milli, micro, etc) and when the person does this it multiplies or divides the value by a number to convert it into the requested unit of measurement. For example, if they wanted to convert centimeters to kilometers i want the user to input for example 200 centimeters  and then for a function to divide that by 1000 to get 0.002km and to print it to the user. But I have no idea how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not trying to do your homework, but this should give you a first idea:

```
factor = {'km': 3,
          'm': 0,
          'dm': -1,
          'cm': -2,
          'mm': -3}  # dictionary with powers, e.g. 1 km = 10**3 m
# For your example of 200 cm = 0.002 km, you type...
number = float(input('numerical value: '))  # 200
unit = input('unit: ')  # cm
target_unit = input('target unit: ')  # km

print(number * 10**factor[unit] / 10**factor[target_unit], target_unit)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [QuantiPhy](https://quantiphy.readthedocs.io/en/stable) package will do this for you.

```
>>> from quantiphy import Quantity
>>> for v in '1MHz 10ug 1ps'.split():
...     q = Quantity(v)
...     print(v, q, 1/q, sep=', ')
1MHz, 1 MHz, 1e-06
10ug, 10 ug, 99999.99999999999
1ps, 1 ps, 1000000000000.0
```

For each case in this example the original string is printed along with the value of the quantity and its reciprocal. This was done to show that quantities are rendered naturally with SI scale factors and units, and that you can use them anywhere a float can be used.